# Using Python update dict method, is it possible to only update one key, value pair?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

If I have two dicts as below:

```
dict1 = {'k1':'v1', 'k2':'v2', 'k3':'v3'}
dict2 = {'k1':'v4', 'k4':'v5', 'k5':'v6'}
```

is it possible to update dict1 using dict 2, but only on a single key, in this case `'k1'` so that the result is as follows:

```
dict1 = {'k1':'v4', 'k2':v2', 'k3':'v3'}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain, why you gave downvotes? I think my question was quite clear and valid. If I broke a SO rule, then please inform me so I don't do it again.

Comment: Hover over the down arrow and read the message that appears. At least two people must have agreed with it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just access each dict using the keys and reassign the value of dict1's key to the value of dict2's key:

```
dict1 = {'k1':'v1', 'k2':'v2', 'k3':'v3'}
dict2 = {'k1':'v4', 'k4':'v5', 'k5':'v6'}
dict1["k1"] = dict2["k1"]
dict1
{'k3': 'v3', 'k2': 'v2', 'k1': 'v4'}
```

To address your comment:

if you used `dict1.update(dict2)` you would add any new `key/values` pairs from `dict2` to `dict1` or change the value of any existing keys in `dict1` to the values of the corresponding keys in `dict2`.

The output would be:

```
{'k3': 'v3', 'k2': 'v2', 'k1': 'v4', 'k5': 'v6', 'k4': 'v5'}
```

As jon Clements suggests, in case dict2 did not have a corresponding key use `dict.get` with a default value of `dict1["k1"]` will keep the original value of dict1's key and avoid a `keyError`:

```
dict1['k1'] = dict2.get("k1",dict1["k1"])
```

And as per abarnet's comment, we can check if both keys exist before accessing either:

```
if "k1" in dic1 and "k1" in dict2:
    dict1["k1"] = dict2["k1"]
```

Comment: It's that easy? What the use of the .update method then?

Comment: Exceptions could still occur on the `dict2` lookup... So, if the specific use-case requires an exception, this is fine. However, another consideration (that's more in-line with `dict.update` that either corresponding key values aren't updated (or new should be added))` is `dict1['k1'] = dict2.get('k1', dict['k1'])` - that way, if a suitable replacement doesn't exist, then keep the original

Comment: @JonClements, do you mean `dict2.get('k1', dict1['k1'])`?

Comment: Using d1['k1'] as the default value for d1['k1'] seems like a lot of hassle to go through just to avoid an if statement. Especially since now it will raise if d1 didn't originally have the key, instead of raising if d2 didn't, which seems like an even more likely scenario.

Comment: @bagelboy: the use of update is that it lets you update all of the items from dict2 at once, without having to loop over them. It's simpler, more concise, more readable, and even more efficient.

Comment: @abarnert I'm making the assumption (of course - sometimes a fallacy) that the key always exists on the base dictionary... that avoids the the explicit contains lookup... that to me makes more sense as if that if you're trying to "update" something that doesn't exist, that's a proper error, rather than trying to update from a corresponding key that doesn't (otherwise, you'd just use `.update()` with a key-value pair)

Comment: This is why I did not add any more to my answer, I knew it would be opening a can of worms. Well we are now checking that both keys exist so if anyone can find a way to get an error now good luck to them!

Comment: @JonClements: Well, the "update" method the OP started off with certainly doesn't give errors if the updated keys don't already exist. Also, you're only avoiding an implicit contains lookup by doing an explicit getitem lookup to get the default value, which is hardly an improvement.